# Why only can get the whole sliced reverse list omitting start and end?

Tags: python, list, slice, python-2.x

Why an sliced list of negative step (or stride) can't get the whole list?

```
>>> my_list = range(1,11)
>>> reverse_list = my_list[10:0:-1]
>>> reverse_list
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
>>> reverse_list = my_list[11:0:-1]
>>> reverse_list
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
>>> reverse_list = my_list[11:-1:-1]
>>> reverse_list
[]
>>>
```

But, if omitted `start` and `end` it works!

```
>>> reverse_list = my_list[::-1]
>>> reverse_list
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Because the end point is *not included* when slicing. And could just omit *just the end*, but leave in a start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the end index `0` is not included.

The better way, as you stated, is:

```
>>> my_list[10::-1]
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Or you can use `None` (as @MartijnPieters suggested):

```
>>> my_list[10:None:-1]
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Or you can use `None`.

Comment: `>>> my_list = range(1,11)
>>> reverse_list = my_list[10:-1:-1]
>>> reverse_list
[]`  Don't works

Comment: Note that `-1` as an endpoint translates to `len(my_list) - 1`, **not** a literal `-1`! Slicing from `[10:-1:-1]` then is the same as `[10:9:-1]` which is an *empty slice*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Yes I was trying it out and just realized. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Trimax, I have removed that suggestion. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, with None at end point it works fine.  But, why not with 0 or -1?

Comment: @Trimax, With `0`, it does not include it. Just like range(1,11) gets from 1 to 10 and not from 1 to 11. For -1, it takes it as the syntax `[-1]` which gets the last element of the list. Best way would be to do `[::-1]`

Comment: @Trimax: The end index is not included, so you'd step from 10, to 9, to 8, etc. to 1. Then stop, because 0 as endpoint is excluded. `None` or leaving it empty means the default, which is 'until exhausted'.

Comment: Thanks to both @MartijnPieters and sshashank124 !

Comment: @Trimax, No problem. Glad to have helped.

Comment: @Trimax: negative indices are always translated to be relative to the length. So -1 really means length_of_the_list minus 1, in this case 9. Stepping down from 10, 9 is not included in the list. Remember that 9 is the highest index in a 0-based indexing system, not 10!

Comment: @Trimax: but `[9:-11:-1]` works again to produce the whole list in reverse..